# Create a ClassLibrary in .NET is compatible with all the frameworks

Tags: .net, servicestack

I want to create a compatible ClassLibraray, But I don't know how to create it. 
 e.g:

[image: Project Property]

[image: References]

Comment: With all Chinese, I don't even know what the dialogs say. There is no target that would be able to be used in *all* frameworks. Your best bet is probably to use .NET Standard.

Comment: I have a .NET Standard ClassLibraray references `ServiceStack`, Web Project use .NET Framework 4.6.1, references `ServiceStack`  and ClassLibraray before. Class not compatible in ServiceStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [HelloMobile/ServiceModel.csproj](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/blob/master/src/ServiceModel/ServiceModel.csproj)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net46</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Which creates a multi-targeted class library which is used in [each supported App Host](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#servicestack-server-app), e.g:

- ASP.NET Core 2.0
- ASP.NET Core running on .NET Framework v4.7
- Classic ASP.NET Framework v4.6
- Self-Host HttpListener on .NET Framework v4.6

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help that you had offered me.